# Обработка ответа в формате JSON

Tags: php, laravel5, guzzle

Есть ответ в формате json (запрос отправлял через Guzzle Laravel, использовал готовый API), я его десериализовал через json_decode.

```
public function raspget(RaspRequest $request)
{
  $client = new Client([
  'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:8080',
  ]);
  $attributes = $request->only(['departure_station', 'arrival_station', 'date']);
  $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/search/', [
    'query' => [
      'apikey'          => 'I_WONT_TELL_YOU',
      'from'            => $attributes['departure_station'],
      'to'              => $attributes['arrival_station'],
      'date'            => $attributes['date'],
      'lang'            => 'ru_RU',
      'transport_types' => 'suburban',
    ]
  ]);
  $times = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
  return view('rasps.raspgot')->withTimes($times);
}
```

Так как ответ хранит в себе расписание на текущий день, мне нужно отобразить его в blade в таблице через цикл foreach. У меня вылетает ошибка: Undefined Index. Как мне получать данные из ответа и выводить в blade?
Структура ответа здесь: https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/doc/reference/schedule-point-point-docpage/

Comment: `Undefined Index` означает, что вы пытаетесь получить элемент массива, которого нет. Возможно в вашем шаблоне попытка получить элемент, которого нет в `$times` или ошибка в написании ключа

Comment: Покажите код шаблона Blade

Comment: Обычный цикл foreach для вывода в таблицу:

Comment: @foreach ($times as $time)

Comment: {{ $time->title }}

Comment: @endforeach - конец цикла

Comment: код шаблона: https://github.com/Pirate1953/rzd1/blob/master/resources/views/rasps/raspgot.blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему!!!
Так как нам известно число рейсов расписания, которые мы ищем, нужно загрузить сперва это число из JSON-ответа: $total = $times['pagination']['total'];
Далее в шаблон blade мы передаём тот самый ответ $times и параметр $total и уже в самом шаблоне делаем цикл for в таблицу:

```
    @for ($key = 0; $key < $total; $key++)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $times['segments'][$key]['from']['title'] }}{{__(' - ')}}{{$times['segments'][$key]['to']['title'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $times['segments'][$key]['departure'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $times['segments'][$key]['arrival'] }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endfor
```